# XPath: is it possible to combine queries

Tags: xml, xpath

Consider the following XML:

```
<root>
  <steps>
    <step>1</step>
    <step>2</step>
    <step>3</step>
    <step>4</step>
  </steps>
  <stepDetails step="1">Details</stepDetails>
  <stepDetails step="2">Details</stepDetails>
  <stepDetails step="3">Details</stepDetails>
</root>
```

What I need to do is find all the steps that do not have corresponding stepDetails.  In the above example, only the "<step>4</step>" node would be returned.

Now, I know I can do that by querying all the steps, iterating through the collection and performing another query for each iteration.  I'm hoping that there is a way of doing that with just one query.  Perhaps using something like SQL's IN statement and a sub-query.

Any ideas or tips would be most appreciated.

thnx,
Christoph

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
/root/steps/step[not(. = /root/stepDetails/@step)]
```

Comment: So would the reverse query be:

/root/stepDetails/@step[not(. = /root/steps/step)]

?  If I comment out any of the steps (e.g. step 3), that XPath query will find it.  Is there any way to get step 4 included in a query result?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a reverse query, but if you are trying to find stepDetails without any corresponding step I would do: /root/stepDetails[not(@step = /root/steps/step)] - as for including step 4 I think it is included in the results from the query I gave in the answer?

Comment: Yes, I should have been a bit more clear.  Your xpath query goes from steps to stepDetails (which is the answer to what I asked).  I'm trying now to get my head around what the reverse query would look like -- going from stepDetails to steps (ie, finding all the stepDetails nodes that do not have corresponding steps).  Removing the step 3 node, the query in my comment will find the step="3" stepDetails node.  But I'm not sure if my xpath was correct.  I was also wondering if there was a way to also get it to return the step 4 step node along with the step 3 stepDetails node.

Comment: how can I do something like this using predicates?

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="steps" match="//root/stepDetails" use="@step" />

  <xsl:template match="//root">
    <root>
      <steps>
      <xsl:for-each select="steps/step[not(key('steps',text()))]">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </steps>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>



  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```